# how do you change the dataType in sendRequest

Tags: randori

For my project I need to change the dataType to "jsonp". How is this possible? I can't seem to find the function. Similar to in jquery.ajax datatype

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Jon,

I recommend using the jQuery API for jsonP requests right now. That support is not natively part of the AbstractService.

Mike